# preview layouts android studio error on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

when i try to rendering and preview layouts on android studio on ubuntu 14.04 i've this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.multi.RenderPreview.<init>(RenderPreview.java:186)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.multi.RenderPreview.create(RenderPreview.java:459)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.multi.RenderPreviewManager.addScreenSizePreviews(RenderPreviewManager.java:1187)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.multi.RenderPreviewManager.recomputePreviews(RenderPreviewManager.java:781)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.multi.RenderPreviewManager.selectMode(RenderPreviewManager.java:822)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ConfigurationMenuAction$PreviewAction.actionPerformed(ConfigurationMenuAction.java:262)
at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionPopupStep$1.run(PopupFactoryImpl.java:733)
at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup$18.run(AbstractPopup.java:1248)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.flushRequest(FocusManagerImpl.java:651)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.flushNow(FocusManagerImpl.java:632)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.flushIdleRequests(FocusManagerImpl.java:602)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.access$200(FocusManagerImpl.java:60)
at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl$IdleRunnable.runEdt(FocusManagerImpl.java:108)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.EdtRunnable$1.run(EdtRunnable.java:28)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

i've install it by ppa and i've 0.8.13 versione of android studio. how can i fix that?

Comment: try upgrading AS. http://askubuntu.com/questions/421389/where-to-unpack-the-android-studio-file

Comment: This assertion is firing because you don't have the target device set up correctly. Don't know why the UI isn't catching it and giving you a friendly error.